# Any relation between primorial numbers and oblong (n(n+1)) numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primorial

Just noticed that some primorial numbers are oblong:

$\prod\limits_{i=1}^{3}p_i = 5 \cdot 6$

$\prod\limits_{i=1}^{4}p_i = 14 \cdot 15$

$\prod\limits_{i=1}^{7}p_i = 714 \cdot 715$

Does anyone know if there are infinite cases of numbers that are at the same time oblong and primorial?

Comment: Do you mean with "oblong" twice a triangle number ? Then, a number is "oblong" if and only if $4k+1$ is a perfect square.

Comment: [A related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3497587/) would suggest that such numbers are quite rare.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Products involving the first $n$ primes, wherein two products differ by 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562569/products-involving-the-first-n-primes-wherein-two-products-differ-by-1) (You are looking at the [A161620](https://oeis.org/A161620) sequence. There are no known examples larger than $714\cdot 715$)

Comment: It seems that $510510$ is the largest primorial of the form $n(n+1)$. If another one exists, ist must be very large.

Comment: @Vepir I just test the range upto $10^6$#

Comment: @Peter According to the OEIS link, there are no examples below [$A034386$](https://oeis.org/A034386)$(10^{11})$.

Comment: @Vepir OK, consider it as a doublecheck. $10^{11}$# ? Really a huge search limit !

Comment: Note that 714 and 715 are Babe Ruth's and Hank Aaron's career home run records.  Pal Erdos had a baseball with those numbers on it, signed by Hank Aaron.  That means Aaron's Erdos number is 1.  I think Ron Graham has the baseball now.  The problem of finding the next pair of such numbers is in Guy's UPINT.  It's a fairly famous unsolved problem.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruth–Aaron_pair

Answer (score 1):

This PARI/GP program

```
(22:05) gp > n=1;s=1;while(n<10^6,n=nextprime(n+1);s=s*n;if(issquare(4*s+1)==1,print(n," ",s)))
2 2
3 6
5 30
7 210
17 510510
(22:11) gp >
```

shows that upt $10^6$# , there is no larger primorial than $510510$, which has the form $n(n+1)$. This leads to the strong conjecture that there are no more. To prove it, will be very difficult, I guess.

Comment: The OEIS entry apparently claims that the list is complete upto $10^{11}$#, my search limit however lets already almost no hope for another solution.